# Ошибка в Outlook

Tags: outlook

При сканировании документа через сканер CANON, используя приложение от CANON, в настройках установили что бы файл автоматически вставлялся в новое письмо через OUTLOOK, но после сканирования выдает ошибку.
[image: ошибка]

Comment: И что установили в настройках?

Comment: Ну там просто список приложение, и выбрали outlook